# How to get back the brightness-notification when changing brightness via hotkeys?

Tags: laptop, shortcut-keys, notify-osd, brightness

Some Ubuntu-versions ago, there was a Popup that showed up while changing the brightness on my Asus V6V with FN+Key. It has been gone since (I guess) 9.04. When changing the Audio-Volume, I still have such a thing.

[image]

How can I get this back/working again?

Comment: I dont think,it's an ubuntu feauture..Your laptop might have some drivers for that..

Comment: @karthick87 this is what he means: http://i.imgur.com/BKqfl.png added a screen shot to the question - revert if I made a mistake ;-)

Comment: It's still here on my Asus UL20A running 10.10.

Comment: You can press the brigthness adjustment keys and look in dmesg for ACPI related errors.

Comment: The only interesting messages I get there are "asus_laptop: Error calling BSTS" and "asus_laptop: Error calling CWAP(1)"

Answer (score 2):

If the brightness controls still work, but the display is missing, then it's possible that the keys are going directly to your hardware (bios perhaps) and not being interpreted by xinput or any of the input subsystem.

In both 10.04 and 10.10 the system will show a notification if the brightness is changed via an input.

If you upgraded, it could be a problem with the notifications.